# Quick way to define PHP variables based on MySQL table field names

Tags: php, mysql

When retrieving values from a MySQL table using PHP, how can I efficiently define a set of variables based on the names of the fields in the MySQL table?

In the past I have been able to do something along the following lines:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    explode ($row);
    ...
}
```

And this has defined a load of variables with the same names as the field names in my table.

I cannot for the life of me remember what the `explode ($row)` bit was though. Thanks.

Comment: This will really clutter your local namespace. What's so bad about `$row['field']`?

Answer (score 3):

Possibly [Extract](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)?

Comment: Thanks, that was the one I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

The results of a `mysql_fetch_array` are delivered into an associative array.

There are a couple of ways to convert the variables in an associative array into simple variables. The most common way is to use the [`list()` function](http://uk.php.net/list). Another is the [`extract()` function](http://uk.php.net/extract).

However, I would urge you to rather just stick with using the associative array that you are given intially.

If you read the manual page for `extract()`, you'll note that they make a point of warning about it being a potential security risk. Its use is generally discouraged (although it isn't formally deprecated at this point).

Using `list()` is more common, and does not represent the same risk as `extract()`, but is still unnecessary in most cases.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will leave `extract()` alone!

Comment: @Chris -- cool. :-)  If it allowed you to do anything that you couldn't do otherwise then it would be fair enough, but there's no point exposing yourself to a known security risk for zero benefit.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably thinking of the [`list()`](http://us.php.net/manual/function.list.php) function.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  list($col1, $col2, $col3) = $row;
   ...
}

// Or more concise:
while (list($col1, $col2, $col3) = mysql_fetch_array ($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   echo $col1;
   echo $col2;
   ...
}
```

However, I would probably not use `list()`. I'd much prefer to access the columns directly from the associative array as `$row['col1'], $row['col2'], $row['col3']` so as not to litter the global namespace with short-lived variables.

Comment: Thanks. The content of the table is changing a lot at the moment hence why I wanted something quick and easy.

Answer (score 1):

You mean [`extract()`](http://php.net/extract).

Comment: Interesting - I never knew about the `extract()` function.